# Macro changing "page setup" not working

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have a simple macro that was recorded to format some cells and also setup some some page formatting (margins footer header ect..) The macro runs without errors and it formats the cells just fine but does not save/change any of the page setup options. After i run it if i check the page setup everything is still at default. Below is the page setup portion. I have tried this on multiple files/workbooks it does not seem to save the changes no matter what. Any ideas?

Thanks

```
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .LeftHeader = ""
    .CenterHeader = "&F"
    .RightHeader = ""
    .LeftFooter = ""
    .CenterFooter = "Page &P of &N"
    .RightFooter = ""
    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
    .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
    .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
    .PrintGridlines = True
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
End With
```

Comment: Works for me in Excel 2013; which version are you using?

Comment: honestly when you said that i thought that might be the problem because it was originally recorded on another machine that i think has 2010 but i just rerecorded it and then opened up a new workbook and tried it and it still doesn't keep the changes. Very odd

Comment: Works for me on 2010.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and later after some research, found the solution below.

*"You cannot use page setup properties in Excel if no printers were installed"*

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291298

I hope this helps. Thanks.